# Evaluation of the notable aspects of patent "Transistor implemented heat source" (Patent number: 10887947)

Tags: transistors, heat

I recently came across a patent titled ["Transistor implemented heat source" (Patent number: 10887947)](https://patents.justia.com/inventor/junior-darian-vargas) and I'm curious to know how notable or significant this invention is in the field of electronics. The patent describes a heat source comprised of one or more transistors or transistor packages mechanically connected to a heat plate. The heat generation is achieved through the precise duty cycle control of a high-frequency Pulse-Width-Modulated (PWM) based on the sensed temperature and current generated by the transistor(s).

There is a video that provides a more detailed explanation of how the invention works. [Video: Electronic Heat](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dLnhg6LD9Nc)

Could anyone familiar with the field of electronics and patents provide an assessment of the novelty and importance of this patent?

Thank you in advance for your insights and expertise.

Comment: "Novelty" = "old hat."  "Importance" = "Only for patent lawyers to make money from."  There have been many people who have used transistors as heat sources.

Comment: @JRE, hmm... I see. Could you cite some examples?

Comment: There is nothing new or original in this. If the patent office granted a patent (it wasn't clear to me) then they are a joke.

Comment: @EmmanuelJoséGarcía:  [Here's one made by a hobbyist.](https://hackaday.com/2023/03/29/mosfet-heater-is-its-own-thermostat/)  It uses the MOSFET itself as a heating element and as a temperature sensor.

Comment: I recall seeing temperature controlled crystal oscillators back in the 1990s that used a MOSFET as a heating element to keep the crystal at the correct temperature.

Comment: Man, I know they say the patent office is useless these days, but they really are useless...

Comment: @EmmanuelJoséGarcía https://www.edn.com/use-a-transistor-as-a-heater/

Comment: In electronic engineering, if someone thinks they have discovered something original and significant, are there specialized journals that evaluate the originality and relevance of the "invention"? If there are, what are these journals?

Comment: @EmmanuelJoséGarcía This is a really good question.  I would edit it into your original question at the end.  It would be great to see some discussion about this subject here.

Comment: @EmmanuelJoséGarcía I don't think such a question is on-topic for this site.

Comment: If there is no prior patent on the idea of using this specific combination of components, frequencies, etc as described in the patent, then there is a good chance the patent will be awarded.  That doesn't mean it is enforceable though.  Often times the reason no one has patented something before is that it has been in use for so long and by so many people it would be impossible to enforce and thus a waste of money to patent.

Comment: For those who closed this question, I want to ask how it is that asking about the novelty of the "invention" in question is based on opinion. Concrete examples of previous use of this "invention" have been given here, or have they not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here](https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/21/d1/99/ccfa7be7e9aee2/US10887947.pdf) is the patent PDF. I agree with the others, there's nothing new or novel here, looks like something a novice hobbyist cooked up with an Arduino Nano and some (very expensive) [1kV SiC MOSFET](https://www.mouser.ca/datasheet/2/240/ixys_s_a0008595787_1-2273251.pdf)s. Using semiconductors as heaters is nothing new. They're limited to low temperatures due to the package construction, for one thing, so it's seldom done. For something like ovenizing a crystal or voltage reference it's usable. [Here](https://www.edn.com/use-a-transistor-as-a-heater/), for example, is a published design idea that predates the patent application. Anyone can find that in a few seconds from a search engine.

There are different motivations for seeking a patent, and not all of them make economic sense, and fewer again are in the spirit of protecting genuine innovation for the benefit of the inventor. This might be a vanity patent or to justify work to a funding source, or to pad the IP portfolio of a company.

I also have serious doubts about the reliability of deliberately and continuously running MOSFETs in a pulsed short-circuit condition, not to mention the nasty EMI from running at extreme low duty cycle and fast switching. Anecdotally, the safe operating area (SOA) of MOSFETs is calculated rather than measured, and not necessarily conservative.

Answer (score 3):

Not necessarily answering the question, but to clarify a bit about patents in general.

As they are now, and as I understand it (so, correct me in comments if I'm going off on a limb here, and, obligatory "not legal advice") -- they are strictly a mechanism to pursue legal action.  That is, a type of IP (intellectual property) law and enforcement.

Mechanically speaking, all that a patent does is represent some abstract object (it might be a real object, just a description of one, or merely a manner of doing things(!)), over which the owner can file a legal proceeding.  That is, it grants the legal right to sue under patent law.

The subject of that legal right, turns out not to be particularly important.

By granting patents very liberally* (or irresponsibly, as the case may be), the USPTO is simply manufacturing ammunition of a legal nature.  Basically, they're hands-off as far as vetting the quality of that ammunition.  It's up to the party/ies involved to gauge whether that ammunition is any good -- by firing it on the legal battlefield.  The intent is perhaps that, by trying them directly, the quality/value of a patent can be determined by its owner.

*Here using "liberal" in the "they do it a lot" or "easily completed" sense.  In the political meaning of "liberal", this might indeed be beyond the state of things a strictly liberal philosopher/government might prefer...  Now, I won't be making any statements regarding the present political state of the USA, but it is interesting to put these facts up into the air and gesture at them suggestively.

This ammunition doesn't have to be very powerful to still have monetary value.  If a would-be target decides it would cost, say, $10k to file a response to a suit, just to dismiss it on facial grounds -- the plaintiff asking $5k to settle is a no-brainer.  Repeat this a hundred times per year, and that plaintiff might rack up a sustainable income.  Repeat for hundreds of patents, and various other kinds of IP (copyright, etc.), and you might have a [patent troll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patent_troll) (and the analogous versions for other legal rights).

Because there is no mechanism to collect such actions together (at least, not automatically), and there might not be enough value to organize a class action suit (a complicated and costly action), these patents tend to go unchallenged.

Note also that, even if a defendant is determined to see the case through -- to obtain a judgement against the [clearly ludicrous](https://patents.google.com/patent/US6368227B1/en)* patent at issue -- the plaintiff can simply drop the case.  Cases are only decided when both parties consent to the decision, so there's no way to force such a result.  Thus, while the plaintiff might make no profit from such an attempt, the defendant is still set with all their legal fees.  (Laws vary by jurisdiction; some allow shifting legal fees to the plaintiff in cases like these, for precisely this reason.)

*Linked for comedic effect; I don't know if this particular one has actually been used in any action.

There is a popular belief that patents protect inventors; indeed, that is its stated purpose.  But [that hasn't](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edwin_Howard_Armstrong#Death) [been true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Kearns#Intermittent_wipers) for a long time.  At least, not universally so.

This topic is an excellent illustration of a phenomenon that occurs often in the real world: some object, or idea, or system, might be created with certain ideals in mind (e.g., patents to protect and reward investors, and further the state of ingenuity overall); perhaps it serves in such a capacity for some time, even; but, when broken down to its most fundamental mechanisms, that thing really is a method of doing other things, and perhaps can be [mis]used in ways different from its original intent, or indeed even [ab]used in ways directly counter to its stated intent.

Therefore, we must always look at systems carefully and critically, and understand what's going on within them.  Never take things at face value, but seek out the relationships between elements or agents in that system.  This phenomenon is especially common when something important is at stake -- anything from the pride of winning a video game (whether by exploiting game mechanics, or explicit cheating), to the distribution of value in the whole world economy.

It is at this point we lose sight of the topic of electrical engineering, but we can perhaps generalize our talent for systems analysis, and apply it to a topic of political engineering, as it were, to better understand how and why these kinds of situations come about.